# How to propagate TSTP while running a program as a different user

Tags: command-line, su, signals, suspend

I'm running a terminal application via "su" in this fashion:

```
su -c "/path/to/app --args" username
```

This is done from a root context, and 'username' is a less privileged user in the system.  The application has signal handlers for CTRL-C and CTRL-Z (SIGINT and SIGTSTP, respectively).  One odd problem I've come across is that CTRL-Z does not appear to propagate to the application when run via 'su' in this fashion.  If I remove the 'username' from the end of the command above, then it works fine.  Only when there is a user switch using su does this signal not work.

Is there a way to allow TSTP to propagate through to a program being executed as a different user?

Tested using CentOS 6.4; GNU Coreutils 8.4

Comment: Seems to me that a better solution might be to use sudo instead of su.

Comment: 'sudo -u username /path/to/app --args' does indeed work.  IMO this answers the question, so please submit and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'sudo' instead of 'su' solved the problem, as suggested by mdpc.